# Why is my page refreshing when I click on a certain button?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem. I have 2 div, which one is hidenn by default. I wrote this code, but when i press on second div button, my page starting refreshing.

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('body').on('click', '.actprn', function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    });

$('body').on('click', '.actscn', function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

HTML

```
 <form>
<div class="infpers">
            <div class="actprn row">
                <div class="col-md-4"> <h2> Main Information</h2></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit"> &#8691;</button></div>
            </div>
 <div class="mainId">
    ....
  </div>

   <div class="actscn row">
                <div class="col-md-4"> <h2>Informations secondaires</h2></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"> &#8691;</button></div>
            </div>
            <div class="formsc" style="display: none;"> 
             ...
            </div>
            </form>
```

I think it's because *style="display: none;"*  but maybe I miss something else.

Comment: `<button>` by default submit the form they are in when clicked.  If you do not want the form to submit, either preventDefault on the event, or put `type="button"` on the button

Comment: @Taplar, answers go down there. You short-circuit the SO process when you put them up here.

Comment: @Taplar but first button is also submit, but works fine?

Comment: The first button should be behaving the same way.  If it is not causing the page to refresh, then there is some logic you did not include in the question that is preventing the submit

Comment: *"but works fine?"* what does that means? What is the button doing? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @FelixKling function <i> slideToggle()</i> works fine

Comment: @Taplar, thank you for help